# How to display restful request and response on the browser. My client wants to debug the request and response from client application

Tags: java, web-services

I created a swing client application which calls Restful api. I want to display both request and response. I could display response but request since it is a URI i could not print it in a xml format. How to display the request

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of browser plugins that'll let you construct a request to RESTful services. My favorite is [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

It'll let you type in the URI, required headers, and body, and displayes the results. Very useful for debugging RESTFul services.

Comment: I think I framed my question wrong. I want to show that in swing application. So I have a java class that acts like a client for webservice. I have to display request in xml format on swing UI. So i need Restful request to be displayed in xml format in swing so I want to capture request in java objects so that i can convert it into xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have found RESTClient to be nice. Its available in both chrome and firefox.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Personally I've only used the one on Firefox since there's where I do any of my debugging.